# WebAPI経由で取得したJSONをTextViewに表示しようとするとアプリが落ちてしまう

Tags: android, kotlin, webapi

Kotlinでwebapiにpostしています。

返ってきたjsonをtextviewに表示しようとすると落ちてしまうのですが、何処がおかしいのでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

apiは便宜的にjsonをオウム返しするものを作りました。

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.eclipsesource.json.Json
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val URL = "https://www.hoge.com/test.php"
        val sendDataJson = "{\"id\":\"foo@hoge.com\",\"pw\":\"pass\"}"
        val getButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonGet) as Button
        getButton.setOnClickListener {
            getButton.setEnabled(false)
            onParallelGetButtonClick(URL,sendDataJson)
        }
    }

    //非同期処理でHTTP GET or POSTを実行します。
    fun onParallelGetButtonClick(URL: String, sendDataJson: String) = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val getButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonGet) as Button
//        val textView = findViewById(R.id.text) as TextView
//        ここのコメントを外すと落ちる。

        val http = HttpUtil()
        //Mainスレッドでネットワーク関連処理を実行するとエラーになるためBackgroundで実行
        val deferred = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
            http.httpPost(URL,sendDataJson)
        }
        deferred.await().let {
            //minimal-jsonを使って　jsonをパース
            val result = Json.parse(it).asObject()
            val ret1 = result.getString("id", "no id data")
            Log.d("TAG",ret1)

//            textView.setText(ret1)
//            ここでテキストビューに表示したい。

            getButton.setEnabled(true)
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.toRequestBody

object HttpClient {
    //OKHttp3はシングルトンで使う
    val instance = OkHttpClient()
}

class HttpUtil {
    private val JSON_MEDIA = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
    fun httpPost(url : String, jsonBody : String): String? {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(jsonBody.toRequestBody(JSON_MEDIA))
            .build()

        val response = HttpClient.instance.newCall(request).execute()
        val body = response.body?.string()
        return body
    }
}
```

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'  //http通信ライブラリ
    implementation 'com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.5' //jsonパースライブラリ
    def coroutines_version = '1.3.9' //Kotlin coroutines用ライブラリ(async, await)のバージョン
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version" //Kotlin coroutines用ライブラリ(async, await)
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version" //Kotlin coroutines用ライブラリ(async, await)
}
```

```kotlin
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get/Post"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonGet"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

```kotlin
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

```
<?php
    //本番かデバッグか(json受け渡しの切替用)
    $debug = false;
if ($debug) {
    //デバッグモード
    $json = array(
        "id"=>"foo@hoge.com",
        "pw"=>"pass"
    );
} else {
    //本番モード
    $body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($body, true);
}
    http_response_code(200);    //HTTPレスポンスコード(200正常終了)
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
    echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    exit(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlinコードでは`findViewById(R.id.text)`でアクセスしようとしているのに、ActivityのレイアウトXMLとおぼしきコードでは`android:id="@+id/textView"`となっています。`text`というIDを持つUI要素を本当に定義していますか？　していないのであれば**コンパイルエラー**になっているはずです。

一般的に、「落ちる」というのは、ソフトウェアの実行時にメモリアクセス違反や未処理例外などのランタイムエラーでプロセスが強制終了（クラッシュ）することを指す俗称です。コンパイルエラーは「落ちる」とは言いません。
もし**コンパイルエラー**が発生しているのであれば、IDE (Androidの場合は通常Android Studio) のビルドログとして出力されているコンパイラからのエラーメッセージを参考にしてコードの誤りを修正していきます。最近のIDEは優秀で、単純な構文エラーであれば実際にコンパイルする前にコードエディター上でリアルタイムに検出し、赤字で表示してくれるようになっています。
もし**ランタイムエラー**が発生しているのであれば、デバッグコンソール (Androidの場合は通常Logcat) にシステムやフレームワークから出力されているエラーメッセージを参考にしたり、try-catch例外ハンドラーを明示的に記述して例外を捕捉することでエラーメッセージやスタックトレースを出力したりして、問題のある個所を特定・修正していきます。デバッガーで状態を確認しながらステップ実行し、問題を分析することもあります。

エラーメッセージはご丁寧に日本語にローカライズされていることもありますが、ほとんどは英語です。英語が読めないのであればプログラミング以前の問題であり、まず英語を学習してください。技術文書で使用される英語は平易な構文がほとんどで、最低限高校レベルの英語力があれば大抵なんとかなります。分からない単語はWeb検索で調べれば十分です。機械翻訳もありますが、英語から日本語への翻訳はまだまだ精度が低く、頓珍漢な翻訳をすることが多いのでお勧めしません。

- [ペアプログラミングして気がついた新人プログラマの成長を阻害する悪習 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/hirokidaichi/items/27c757d92b6915e8ecf7#%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)
- [プログラミング言語 - エラー文って読まないの？｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/76445)
- [超初心者のためのコードのデバッグ - Visual Studio | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners?view=vs-2019&tabs=csharp)

Comment: お忙しい中ご解答どうもありがとうございます。お陰様で表示することができました。ご指摘の件、痛み入ります。英語をもう少し勉強させていただきます。

Comment: @たぬき 役に立った回答には「投票」をしてください。また、最も役に立った回答には「承認済み」のマークをしてください。詳細はスタック・オーバーフローのヘルプを熟読してください。日本語による説明が記載されています。 「ツアー - スタック・オーバーフロー」 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour 「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー」 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers